# Get character after certain character from a String

Tags: c#, string

I need to get a characters after certain character match in a string. Please consider my Input string with expected resultant character set.

**Sample String**

```
*This is a string *with more than *one blocks *of values.
```

**Resultant string**

```
Twoo
```

**I have done this**

```
string[] SubIndex = aut.TagValue.Split('*');
            string SubInd = "";
            foreach (var a in SubIndex)
            {
                SubInd = SubInd + a.Substring(0,1);
            }
```

Any help to this will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What have you come up with so far?

Comment: What about this string: "** *** ***** lol"

Comment: @astef:For this string "** *** ***** lol", it should come with empty string (ie, "").

Comment: @DonMax: Why should `"** *** ***** lol"` be empty? By your current rules it would be `"   "` (3 spaces)

Comment: What is wrong with your code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`LINQ` solution:

```
var str = "*This is a string *with more than *one blocks *of values.";
var chars = str.Split(new char[] {'*'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
               .Select(x => x.First());
var output = String.Join("", chars);
```

Comment: Note that if the first character in the string is not a *, it will still be included in the output.

Answer (score 3):

```
string s = "*This is a string *with more than *one blocks *of values.";
string[] splitted = s.Split(new char[] { '*' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string result = "";
foreach (string split in splitted)
    result += split[0];
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: No need for the `IsNullOrEmpty` validation, split will never be empty due to the `RemoveEmptyEntries` flag

Answer (score 2):

Below code should work

```
var s = "*This is a string *with more than *one blocks *of values."
while ((i = s.IndexOf('*', i)) != -1)
{
    // Print out the next char
    if(i<s.Length)
            Console.WriteLine(s[i+1]);

    // Increment the index.
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String.Join("",input.Split(new char[]{'*'},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                    .Select(x=>x.First())
           );
```

Comment: Have you tried it with the sample string? You'll get an exception because of  the empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
string strRegex = @"(?<=\*).";
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Singleline);
string strTargetString = "*This is a string *with more than *one blocks *of values.";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();    
foreach (Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(strTargetString))
{
    if (myMatch.Success) sb.Append(myMatch.Value);
}
string result = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Why does somebody always have to turn up with a regex solution every time somebody needs a string parsing

Comment: There might be more flexibilty needed in some scenarios. For this simple task it is possibly overkill...

Comment: Yes, some scenarios... but this question is not "How can I do something for other scenarios". This question is explicit about requirements and Regex is not a good solution.

Comment: OK, but I use this site mostly as a knowledgebase using already answered questions. It could be useful for someone else.

Comment: Yes, this site is designed to be useful for future visitors. But I don't think it is useful to encourage using regex when it is not appropriate

Answer (score 0):

please see below...

```
char[] s3 = "*This is a string *with more than *one blocks *of values.".ToCharArray();
StringBuilder s4 = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < s3.Length - 1; i++)
{
   if (s3[i] == '*')
     s4.Append(s3[i+1]);
}
Console.WriteLine(s4.ToString());
```